# Finding eigenvalues of circulant matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, circulant-matrices

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha^R&\beta^R &\gamma^R&-\alpha^I&-\beta^I &-\gamma^I\\
\gamma^R&\alpha^R&\beta^R &-\gamma^I&-\alpha^I&-\beta^I \\
\beta^R &\gamma^R&\alpha^R&-\beta^I&-\gamma^I&-\alpha^I \\
\alpha^I&\beta^I &\gamma^I&\alpha^R&\beta^R &\gamma^R\\
\gamma^I&\alpha^I&\beta^I &\gamma^R&\alpha^R&\beta^R \\
\beta^I &\gamma^I&\alpha^I&\beta^R&\gamma^R&\alpha^R \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The above matrix is a block circulant matrix. How to find the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: I'm not sure it's standard to call this a "block circulant" matrix.  I think it could be called a "block matrix with circulant blocks".  (Note that the term BCCB, "block circulant with circulant blocks", is used in the study of image deconvolution.)

Comment: it's eigen vectors are as same as those of $A_r-A_i$ and $A_r+A_i$, right? $A_r = \text{matrix of }\alpha^R$ etc

Comment: No, I don't believe that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to Maple, two of the eigenvalues are 
$$ \alpha^R + \beta^R + \gamma^R \pm i (\alpha^I + \beta^I + \gamma^I)$$
The other four are roots of a rather unpleasant irreducible quartic.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that all matrix-entries are real numbers.

Your matrix can be written in the form
$$
A = \pmatrix{B & -C\\C & B}.
$$
Via the standard identification of $\Bbb C$ with $\Bbb R^2$, we can see that the eigenvalues of $A$ have the form $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\bar\lambda_1, \bar \lambda_2, \bar \lambda_3$, where $\bar z$ denotes the complex conjugate of $z$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ are the eigenvalues of the $3 \times 3$ complex matrix $M = B + iC$.

Because $B + i C$ is itself a circulant matrix, we can [find its eigenvalues systematically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues). In particular, we will have
$$
\lambda_j = (\alpha^R + i\alpha^I) + (\beta^R + i\beta^I)\omega^j + (\gamma^R + i \gamma^I)\omega^{2j} \quad j = 1,2,3,
$$
where $\omega = e^{2 \pi i/3}$.  The eigenvalues in Robert's answer are $\lambda_3,\bar \lambda_3$.